# Nested inner class being ignored in OSGI?

Tags: java, gson, osgi, classloader, apache-karaf

I'm using gson to bind some json to a pojo. When I *don't* use OSGI, everything binds perfectly, so I am feeling like a class type is getting ignored completely due to some classloader issue because the nested collection is null after parsing.

I have an abstract generic class that does the binding within a separate bundle:

```
  public <T> T deserialize(String jsonString, Class<T> clazz) {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    return gson.fromJson(jsonString, clazz);
  }
```

This approach works without OSGI, but when I use OSGI, it only binds the top-level elements that exist within the `T` class, but not the nested inner class.

To better illustrate "top-level" elements, the `title` and `description` are deserialized into the POJO correctly, but theThings is null. Do I need to somehow embed that nested subtype into the generic?

This is the class signature that contains the `deserialize` method.

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T>

{
  "title": "my awesome title",
  "description": "all the awesome things",
  "theThings": [
    {
      "thing": "coolThing1",
      "association-type": "thing"
    },
    {
      "thing": "coolThing2",
       "association-type": "thing"
      }

  ]
}
```

## POJO Class that JSON Binds To:

```
package things;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ThingsPOJO implements Serializable
{
  @SerializedName("title")
  @Expose
  public String title = "";

  @SerializedName("description")
  @Expose
  public String description = "";

  @SerializedName("theThings")
  @Expose
  public List<TheThing> theThings = null;

  private class TheThing implements Serializable
  {

    @SerializedName("thing")
    @Expose
    public String thing = "";

    @SerializedName("association-type")
    @Expose
    public String associationType = "";

  }
}
```

Comment: Typically there may be problems in OSGi if the class that does the serializing and the class to be serialized do not belong to the same bundle. Maybe it is something similar with the generic. You can try to set the thead context classloader to a classloader that sees all necessary classes before calling .fromJson.

Comment: Do you have an example of how this would work?

Comment: Its weird to me that only the nested collection is null

Comment: As a workaround, I made the deserialization function abstract to override in the bundle with the proper loader context. This isn't ideal as I wanted to minimize the implementation of that deserialization function, but _that_ method does work.